# Install and run TestU01: Testing Random Number Generators on windows by cygwin

Tags: c, windows, cygwin

I installed Cygwin on my windows 10. I need to run TestU01(Testing Random Number Generators). I already followed the instruction from [Test01 installation guide](http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/install.html). But I can't run the programs from the example directory and I got a **fatal error:'unif01.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated** when running

> gcc birth1.c -o birth1 -ltestu01 -lprobdist -lmylib -lm

. Please help me to run an example on windows by using Cygwin.